# Identify a comic where US army captures and arrests Wonder Woman

Tags: dc, episode-identification, wonder-woman

There was an old Wonder Woman comic book in which the army captures her, probably because she went rogue or out of control.

Which comic is this ?

Comment: Can you date it approximately, i.e., within a decade or three?

Comment: maybe three decades, from vol. 1, I think...!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Amazons Attack!](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazons_Attack!)**

[image]

From the description on Wikipedia:

> After leaving the DC Universe during the events of Infinite Crisis, the Amazons return to attack Washington, D.C. in retaliation for the American government's illegal detention of Wonder Woman.
>
> The Amazons teleport to Washington, D.C., where Diana is being held captive and tortured by the Department of Metahuman Affairs.

Comment: I thought the OP was looking for something older that 2007, and the Department of Metahuman Affairs isn't the Army, is it? Of course, sometimes the descriptions are a little off.

Comment: It was the only one that I could find that remotely matched the description. We'll see what the OP says...